# ROS2 on hard real time POSIX based RTOS?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to run ROS2 on a POSIX based hard real time RTOS like QNX?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300285/ros2-on-hard-real-time-posix-based-rtos?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no reason you cannot. I don't know if anyone is running it on QNX right now, but I know some people are planning on doing it. There are not existing tutorials or pre-built binaries if that's what you're asking for.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-08-12**:
I was pretty sure that people are going to running ROS2 on QNX but would be interested if someone actually does already :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working for an embedded RTOS vendor eSOL in Japan.
We are currently running both ROS and ROS 2 on our POSIX-compliant RTOS named eMCOS.
You can check further information of eMCOS on the following link.
https://www.esol.com/embedded/emcos.html

---

Originally posted by [akihikotsukuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/37563/akihikotsukuda/) with karma: 13 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1